# Essential curl headers to be included?

Tags: php, curl, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am making an application to make use of the Youtube Data API. I think CURL will always be  a better option than `file_get_contents()` with PHP. With CURL I need to know which all headers should be included with the request for an optimized performance.

I need to set some timeout settings,error handling methods,etc;

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you put sample request/response?

Comment: GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails
                                                  &mine=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http wrapper for file_get_contents (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php):

```
$options = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'timeout' => 60
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
file_get_contents("http://google.com", false, $context);
print_r($http_response_header);
```

Comment: So are u suggesting me file_get_contents instead of curl ?

Comment: It's up to you. Anyway will be used CURL extension.

Answer (score 0):

U can try something like this:

```
    $ch = curl_init('your url');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
                            'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1',
                            'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                            'Accept-Language: ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
                            'Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
                            'Connection: keep-alive',
                            'Pragma: no-cache',
                            'Cache-Control: no-cache'
            ));

            $result = curl_exec($ch);
if($result == FALSE) { 
var_dump(curl_error($ch)); //handling error
} else { //success
echo $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $ch = curl_init();


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $IP);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('User-Agent: 1.11.4 Red Hat modified',"Host : $host",'Connection: Keep-Alive'));//it might need
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,         true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY,         true);//just get the header info only
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,       $timeout);//set your time out
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    return  $data;
```